# How to display a line of a paragraph in bold which is fetched through JSON in android?

Tags: android, json, string

I am taking data from JSON. The fetched data may be a paragraph. So I want to display the heading of the paragraph in bold in android. All the data is stored in online database and fetched using JSON.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How can you "achieve" *what*? Do you need help in downloading the JSON? Parsing the JSON? Parsing text into paragraphs? Parsing headers out of paragraphs? Formatting a `TextView` in bold? Formatting part of a `TextView` in bold? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare:My JSON data is a paragraph.It has a heading.So i want to display the heading in bold.Not the entire paragraph.I am using only one Textview.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Html.fromHtml() to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

Comment: I have used Html.fromHtml() to get the spanned data from JSON.I have modified my JSON paragraph with<b></b> whereever needed.The final result after loading with TextView is empty?

Comment: For paragraph header response return separate parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SpannableString` or `SpannableStringBuilder` as the contents for the `TextView`, and apply a bold `StyleSpan` to whatever the heading is. Or, as Patel Hiren suggests, you could create a snippet of HTML that is what you want, then use `Html.fromHtml()` to get the `Spanned` to put into the `TextView`. Creating the spans directly, rather than through HTML, would be more efficient.

Comment: I have used Html.fromHtml() to get the spanned data from JSON.I have modified my JSON paragraph with<b></b> whereever needed.The final result after loading with TextView is empty?

Comment: @AnishUbais: We cannot help you with code without seeing the code. Perhaps your HTML has problems, where `Html.fromHtml()` is returning `null` or something.